# Spring MVC app, how to configure servlet with jsp views which are inside a dependency jar file

Tags: java, spring, jsp, jar

I have a spring 5 MVC war project, this is not a spring boot project. Now I have a dependency jar, inside the jar there are some jsp files, this jar is added as a dependency in main project.

In the main web app project I have a servlet mapping which is supposed to load the jsp files from inside the dependency jar. I cannot write a view resolver which resolves the jsp files inside the jar. Is there any elegant solutions?

I tried to search in StackOverflow and put the jsp files inside `META-INF/resources/WEB-INF/jsps` and the in the `servlet.xml` file use internalviewresolver with `prefix="WEB-INF/jsps"`. which did not work.

So my questions are:

- Can I show jsp files from dependency jar?
- If so how can i do that using the servlet.xml file?
- What would be the path of the jsp files inside the jar file?

### update

below is the project structure of dependency jar file
[image: project structure of jar library]

below is the view resolver mapping from the servlet in main war project.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

are you using maven to manage your dependencies? I feel like this a minor jsp redirect issue. would be great if you can share your snippets of your xml

Comment: i have updated the description with project structure